# GROUP BY clause / Aggregate function error

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate, errors

I am having a problem creating a Table View:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS product_variation_stock_view;

CREATE VIEW product_variation_stock_view AS
    SELECT
        product_variations.product_id AS product_id,
        product_variations.id AS product_variation_id,
        COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(product_variation_order.quantity), 0), 0) AS stock,
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(product_variation_order.quantity), 0), 0) > 0
            THEN true
            ELSE false
        END in_stock
    FROM product_variations

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            stocks.product_variation_id AS id,
            SUM(stocks.quantity) AS quantity
        FROM stocks
        GROUP BY 
            stocks.product_variation_id
    ) AS stocks USING (id)

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            product_variation_order.product_variation_id as id, 
            SUM(product_variation_order.quantity) AS quantity
        FROM product_variation_order
        GROUP BY 
            product_variation_order.product_variation_id
    ) AS product_variation_order USING (id)
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "product_variations.product_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 3:   product_variations.product_id AS product_id,
      ^
```

Using PostgreSQL 10.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 via Laravel Homestead
I am running the query using the Postico OS X Client.

Comment: You have `SUM` in the topmost `select` clause, so you need a `group by` clause there too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have to change your first few lines to reflect this:

```
CREATE VIEW product_variation_stock_view AS
SELECT
    product_variations.product_id AS product_id,
    product_variations.id AS product_variation_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(product_variation_order.quantity), 0), 0) AS stock,
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(product_variation_order.quantity), 0), 0) > 0
        THEN true
        ELSE false
    END in_stock
GROUP BY product_variations.id, product_variations.product_id
FROM product_variations
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, however I get a new resulting error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"`

Comment: My bad put the group by at the bottom after all of the Joins. Sorry, it's been a long day.

Comment: LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            product_variation_order.product_variation_id as id, 
            SUM(product_variation_order.quantity) AS quantity
        FROM product_variation_order
        GROUP BY 
            product_variation_order.product_variation_id
    ) AS product_variation_order USING (id) 
GROUP BY  product_variations.id, product_variations.product_id

Comment: No problemo! Glad I could help.

Comment: If it solved the problem you should mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates you will need a group by:

```
SELECT  product_variations.product_id AS product_id,
        product_variations.id AS product_variation_id,
        COALESCE(SUM(stocks.quantity) ...
FROM product_variations
...
GROUP BY product_variations.product_id, product_variations.id
```

since you have aggregate functions at the outermost level

Comment: Thanks @Lennart - however I have tried this approach and I get a new resulting error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LEFT"` which is the next line in my query after your suggestion